# How to check all variables created by class function and use them?

Tags: python-3.x

In short; I started coding a few days ago and thought trying to make a simple text based adventure will let me face a lot of problems that I will encounter in other harder projects as well. My class **init** function produces items with some variables, one of which is it's equipment slot position [0-6]. I would like to unequip a slot, but the way I have it set up at the moment requires me to know which item is in that particular slot.

In english: unequip("mainhand"), mainhand has slotnumber 0. Get the info of all equipped items and check which one has the corresponding slotnumber, then remove that particular item.
(Some items have 2 slotnumbers ("althand") which means I will have to find a way to make sure I remove the right item from the list, but that is something I can do later). For now, I can't seem to figure out how to dynamically call items and do stuff with them.

PS. I am pretty sure I can do this in a way more phytonic manner and any suggestions are welcome, but regardless of this, I would still like to know how to dynamically call the function.

The code with which I try this:

```
def Unequip(Slotname): #Slotname is just a string, so I could say: unequip("Mainhand")
        for count,i in enumerate(Item.slotname): #Item.slotname is a list of strings for slots which corresponds with Item.Slot which are the values determining the which slot is occupied.
            if Slotname == Item.slotname[count]: #so when the name I put into the function equals the Item.slotname, I know which number in Item.Slot I need.
                for items in Item: #Here we enter the problem (again, I understand that this code could be a lot better and would love some suggestions).
                #Item is a object, but it's __init__ functions produces items, such as item1, item2 etc. I would like to check if any of these items is currently in my Item.Equipped and has the Item.Slot value I want to remove. 
                #I tried global(), locals() and dir(Item) but none give me what I need. I really hope this makes it clear.
                    if Item.Slot[count]  == items.slot and items.name == Item.Equipped: #I need a susbtitute for the items variable which will represent item1, item2 or item3 etc. So I can do Item.Slot.remove(item2.slot).
                        Slot = Item.Slot.remove(items.slot)
                        Equipped = Item.Equipped.remove(items.name)
                        Player.stats = list(map(operator.sub,list(Player.stats),self.itemstats))
                    elif Item.Slot[i]  == items.altslot and Items.name == items.Equipped:
                        pass
```

Full code (I tried using self etc, but it may not be super readable, my apologies), it includes a item.unequip function but this requires me to select the particular item instead of just the slot from which I want my item to be removed

Edit1: Removed all unneeded stuff per request:

```
import random
import operator
class Item:
    Equipped = []
    Slot = []
    Inventory = []
    num_of_items = 0
    statnames = ["Strength", "Agility", "Dexterity", "Wisdom", "Constitution", "Intelligence"]
    slotname = ["MainHand","Offhand","Head", "Necklace","Chest","Legs", "Cape" ]
    def __init__(self, name, itemstats, slot, altslot = None, atk = None, Def = None): 
        self.itemstats = itemstats #itemstats in order: S, A, D, W, C, I
        self.name = name
        Item.num_of_items += 1
        self.slot = slot
        self.altslot = altslot
        if atk != None and atk != 0:
            self.atk = atk
        if Def != None and Def != 0:
            self.Def = Def

    def Unequip(Slotname):
        for count,i in enumerate(Item.slotname):
            if Slotname == Item.slotname[count]:
                for items in dir(Item):
                    if Item.Slot[count]  == items.slot and items.name == Item.Equipped:
                        Slot = Item.Slot.remove(items.slot)
                        Equipped = Item.Eqiupped.remove(items.name)
                        Player.stats = list(map(operator.sub,list(Player.stats),self.itemstats))
                    elif Item.Slot[i]  == items.altslot and Items.name == items.Equipped:
                        pass

class Player:
    stats= [8,8,8,8,8,8]

    item1 = Item("Sword of damaocles",[5, 1, 0,1,2,-2],0,1,20)
    item2 = Item("Helmet of steel",[9,9,9,9,9,9],2,None,0,20)
```

Comment: Learn more about creating [MCVE], especially **minimal** part.

Comment: Touché, will edit out the unneeded code!